# Getting an attachment field property in a tab menu

Tags: apostrophe-cms

So I am trying to add a custom icon to each menu item by using the simplest menus via tabs but adding an attachment field named "icon" to each page.

What would be the right way to call the url of the icon attachment field?

Here´s the view at it´s simplest:

```
<ul class="b2b-menu">
          {% for tab in data.home._children %}
              <li class="move-link">
                  <a>
                   <img alt="Page Icon" src="{{ apos.attachments.url(attachment) }}" width="48" height="48" />
                   <span>{{ tab.title }}</span>
                   </a>
               </li>
            {% endfor %}
      </ul>
```

Here´s the index.js:

```
module.exports = {
        beforeConstruct: function(self, options) {
            options.addFields = [{
                    name: 'metaDescription',
                    label: 'Meta Description',
                    type: 'string'
                }, 
                {
                    name: 'icon',
                    label: 'Icon',
                    type: 'attachment'
                }]
            } 
        };
```

I can see that tab.icon exists as an object. But I just can´t figure out how to get the URL. Stuff like **tab.icon._url** etc.. do not seem to be the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
{% if tab.icon %}
  <img src="{{ apos.attachments.url(tab.icon, { size: 'one-sixth' }) }}" />
{% endif %}
```

The `tab` variable here assumes you are pasting this code inside your `for` loop, which already introduces it.

The `apos.attachments.url` helper function takes an attachment and an options object and returns a URL, which will be correct regardless of whether you are using uploadfs with local storage, S3 or something else.

For images, if you do not specify the `size` option, you'll get the `full` size. This is a protection against accidental use of the original, which leads to bandwidth problems and can confuse users into believing Apostrophe doesn't offer reasonably scaled sizes. To use the original (which we don't recommend), set `size` to `original`.

For other types of attachments (i.e. `apostrophe-files`), you don't need the size option since linking directly to the file is the only sensible choice.

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: the explanation: tab it's the name in the for loop referring to the object and icon it's the chosen field to render.

Comment: Quite right, my initial answer was too much of a "ta-dah." Details added.